# Not all items sortable with Scriptaculous, Sortables, scroll and overflow

Tags: javascript, yui, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'd like to have a scrollable container with overflow:scroll in which 
a sortable list is contained, like so:

```
<div id="container" style="overflow: scroll; width: 200px; height: 100px;"> 
<ul id="fruit"> 
    <li>Apple</li> 
    <li>Banana</li> 
    <li>Peach</li> 
    <li>Strawberry</li> 
    <li>Cherry</li> 
    <li>Pear</li> 
    <li>Orange</li> 
    <li>Mango</li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

and doing:

```
Sortable.create('fruit', { 
"scroll": "container" 
})
```

This works as long as I choose an item from the visible part of the 
list and if I drop it into the visible part.

If I choose an item from the visible part and try to drop it within 
the invisible region (after scrolling) the other items just don't 
"make room" for it.

If I scroll down and choose an item from the initially invisible part 
and scroll with it to the initially visible part, it is droppable 
between the initially visible items.

Using Prototype 1.6.0.3 and Scriptaculous 1.8.2.

For contrast...what I'm talking about is working in [this YUI example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/dd/scroll-list.html).

Answer (score 4):

In the scriptaculous [documentation](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/sortable-create/), it says to include `Position.includeScrollOffsets = true;` above your `Sortable.create` definition.

You can view a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wXpsB/) here.